# find rows that have similar values to different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have a table in the following format

> ID  | DC1      |          DC2      |   DC3       |     DC4
>
> 1  | black arrow    |    blue box |   brown sugar |   black crown
>
> 2  | red fang      |     yellow scroll| green velvet| white chocolate|
>
> 3  | blue sea|    red fish  |  black window |  great sea

What I need is an ACCESS 2007 query that will return the rows in which any words from DC4 are included in DC1, so in the above case row 1 and 3.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is space the delimiter for each word? Is there a maximum number of spaces expected?

Comment: it can be anything. for example record 1 could be 1| BlaCk (aRRow) | blue box| brown sugar| black crown and i would still need it to show up on my results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to query this data with a simple query.

First, you will need to normalize the data in D4. Since this is Access, you could use a VBA loop to split the values into a different table.

You could do something like this: create a new table "Table2" with integer column `ID` (which does not autoincrement) and text column `DC4`. Then populate Table2 like this:

```
Public Sub SplitValues()

    Dim sourceSet As Recordset
    Dim destinationSet As Recordset
    Dim iterator As Integer
    Dim sourceID As Integer
    Dim stringArray() As String
    Set sourceSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select ID, DC4 From Table1")

    CurrentDb.Execute ("Delete From Table2")

    Set destinationSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2")

    While sourceSet.EOF = False
        sourceID = sourceSet("Id")
        stringArray = Split(sourceSet("DC4").Value, " ")
        For iterator = 0 To UBound(stringArray)
            With destinationSet
                .AddNew
                !ID = sourceID
                !DC4 = stringArray(iterator)
                .Update
            End With
        Next
        sourceSet.MoveNext
    Wend

End Sub
```

Then you can do a query between your original table (let's call it "Table1") and the new table ("Table2"). The query would be something like this:

```
Select Table1.ID, Table1.DC1, Table1.DC4
From Table1
    Inner Join Table2
    On Table1.DC1 Like '*' & Table2.DC4 & '*'
    And Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

If DC4 has multiple values that repeat, you may want to use `Select Distinct`.